# excel data transposition using built in formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Heres the issue I have a dump from the database at work that is in a rather conveluted format. Basically it does not give you the displayed information as much as just the individual relation tables to work with.

EXAMPLE: lets say I have the following columns of information

ID, COLOR, SIZE, QTY, TYPE

the information looks something like this

```
ID  COLOR   SIZE  QTY  TYPE
A   brown   20    1    1
C   yellow  10    2    2
D   brown   40    5    1
A   blue    70    1    3
A   yellow  80    1    2
B   yellow  20    4    1
D   blue    70    4    2
C   blue    10    3    1
```

what i need is something more like this

```
ID  BROWN  SIZE  TYPE  BLUE  SIZE  TYPE  YELLOW  SIZE  TYPE
A   1      20    1     1     0     3     1       80    2
B   0      0     0     0     0     0     4       20    1
C   0      0     0     3     10    1     2       20    1
D   5      40    1     4     0     2     0       0     0
```

I most like could accomplish this with an excel formula, possibly the one called sumifs but i can not seem to get it to work any help with this would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a combination of SUM and IF in array formulas.

Assuming that your data table starts in cell A1 and your result table starts in cell A11, begin by entering the following formulas in cells B12, C12 and D12 respectively, making sure to use the CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER key combination to enter them.

```
B12    =SUM(IF($B$2:$B$9=B$11,IF($A$2:$A$9=$A12,$D$2:$D$9,0)))

C12    =SUM(IF($B$2:$B$9=B$11,IF($A$2:$A$9=$A12,$C$2:$C$9,0)))

D12    =SUM(IF($B$2:$B$9=B$11,IF($A$2:$A$9=$A12,$E$2:$E$9,0)))
```

Copy the cells down to the bottom of your data table, which in this example would be row 15.

Then copy the block of formulas you have created to cell E12, where the BLUE section of the result table starts. Then copy the same block of formulas to cell H12, where the YELLOW section of the result table starts.

This solution assumes that you have no duplicate combinations of ID and COLOR in your data table and that no combinations are missing. If there are missing combinations of ID and COLOR, you would need to wrap the formulas in an IFERROR function (in Excel 2010).

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd transpose a data table would run like this...

Your example is a bit more complicated so I'm not going to use your full data, just go with size. Begin by creating a column called Index

```
A                B   C       D
INDEX            ID  COLOR   SIZE  
=A3 & "-" & B3   A   brown   20    
=A4 & "-" & B4   C   yellow  10    
.                D   brown   40   
.                A   blue    70   
.                A   yellow  80   
.                B   yellow  20   
D-blue           D   blue    70   
C-blue           C   blue    10
```

Create a table equivalent which combines the header row with the ID column

```
F      G                    H             I
ID     brown                blue          yellow
A      =$F2 & "-" & G$1     .             .
B      .                    .             .
C      .                    C-blue        C-yellow    
D      .                    D-blue        D-yellow
```

Finally wrap this up in a VLOOKUP or an OFFSET(MATCH(_)) with possible an IFERROR

```
ID     brown                blue          yellow
A      =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F2 & "-" & G$1,$A$3:$D$10,4,FALSE),"Err")
B      .                    .             .
C      .                    10            10    
D      .                    70            Err
```

Anyway that is how I generally do this sort of transform